# ZF2 Doctrine - using query builder how to point at custom methods in repository

Tags: php, zend-framework2, doctrine

I am struggling with this one and hope someone is able to help.  Building a webapp using ZF2 and Doctrine I am trying to build a query using Doctrine's query builder making use of a custom method in my entity file.  For simple example entity file as follows (shortened for clarity):

```
/**
 * Get firstName
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->firstName;
}

/**
 * Get lastName
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getLastName()
{
    return $this->lastName;
}
public function getFullName()
{
    return $this->getFirstName() . ' ' . $this->getLastName();
}
```

So the first and last name are directly mapped to dB columns, getFullName is a custom method in the entity file.  Then extending the entity with a custom repository for queries I would like to make use of the getFullName method.  I have the following in the repository (which extends the entity file):

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('employee')
    ->from('Application\Entity\Employee', 'employee')
    ->andWhere('employee.fullName = :foo')
    ->setParameter('foo', 'Joe Bloggs');

$query = $qb->getQuery();
```

I was hoping in the andWhere statement it would translate the employee.fullName to find the getFullName method but it appears not.  Does anyone have any ideas please?

Thank you
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: "You can not!". The `getFullName` method has nothing to do with doctrine, because it exists only in the model.

The easiest way to simulate what you want is to split the name into the parts and use it:

```
$fullName = 'Joe Bloggs';
list($firstName, $lastName) = explode(' ', $fullName);
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('employee')
    ->from('Application\Entity\Employee', 'employee')
    ->andWhere('employee.firstName = :first')
    ->andWhere('employee.lastName = :last')
    ->setParameter('first', $firstName)
    ->setParameter('last', $lastName);

$query = $qb->getQuery();
```

Comment: +1 The method could accept the first name and last name as arguments rather than needing to explode a string, i.e `findByFirstAndLastName($firstName, $lastName)`. As you say the `fullName` is not modelled by Doctrine and the return value of the `getFullName()` could change (e.g. `Mr Joe Bloggs`).

Comment: @AlexP you are totally right, it's better to use `$firstName` and `$lastName` as method arguments instead of exploding it. But in my answer, I wanted to be as close as possible on the given example code.